# Getting error "Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$a2hlbpvzpyeu9ywvcwjr1kyb9' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, material-ui, jestjs

I am using Jest to test the following Material-UI component. I would like to assert that the function handleSubmit gets called when the RaisedButton  component is clicked.

```
        //Form.js

export default class Form extends React.Component {    

<RaisedButton
            ref="buttonTag"
            className='SubmitButton'
            label='Go'
            icon={<ActionSearch />}
            onClick={this.handleSubmit} />

        handleSubmit = (event) => {

        };
    }

    //Form-test.js

    import Form from '../../src/Components/Form/Form';
    import React from 'react';
    import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';

    let form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <Form />
    );

    const spy = jest.spyOn(form, 'handleSubmit').mockImplementation(() => {});
    let buttonNode = form.refs.buttonTag; 
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonNode);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

When execution gets to :

```
TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonNode);
```

I get the following error:

```
"Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$a2hlbpvzpyeu9ywvcwjr1kyb9' of undefined"
```

How can I properly simulated a click on the RaisedButton to trigger handleSubmit() ?

Comment: Same here.  "Me, too!"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
let buttonNode = form.refs.buttonTag;
```

How I solved it was to put a plain-jane `ID="myID"` on the button, then get it like this:

```
const buttonNode = document.getElementById("myID");
```

Then do `TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonNode);`